# Newline character lost in IE8 textarea

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to read text from a textarea in IE8 using some JavaScript, using the prototype library selector -  "$F(text-area-id)"

The text I get out of this does not preserve the new lines present in the textarea. Is there any CSS properties I need to set for achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code (ahem), new lines are usually put in "automagically" by the wrapping on the text area.  You can override this with `white-space` style.

Alternatively, you can search your string for the newline character `\n` which sometimes gets "lost in translation".